# Not able to login to wso2 api billing engine

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, billing, wso2-data-services-server

I have configured wso2 api billing engine by following the given document https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Enabling+Monetization+of+APIs . I'm able to sign-up as i can see the entries in appuser table of billing db but i'm not able to login.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox or Chrome it does not work. I was able to login in Microsoft Edge for Windows 10 only. Probably because of outdated client technologies (like Primefaces etc.)